# Get resources that website is using from code?

Tags: html

which is the best way to get a list of resources the website is using? So for example I have a page with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example page</title>
        <script src="js/myscriptjs"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
    </head>
</html>
```

How I can detect the files "js/myscriptjs", "js/jquery.min.js" and "css/mystyle.css"? Is the only way to search for file extensions like ".css", ".js" or ".php"?

Greetings, Flo.

Comment: Really depends on your context. What do you need this for, on what kind of platform?

Comment: If you only need the file names, use `document.querySelectorAll("script[src], link[href]")` or something like that and grab the file names of the returned elements.

Comment: I currently making a small app that needs from specific websites (I already got the code of them) the paths to resource files.

Comment: @Xufox Thanks, I will try it!

Comment: @Xufox Thanks a lot, it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll` to select all elements that refer to a resource. Then get the file names from them. An ECMAScript 6 version could look like this, using both arguments of [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) as well as [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
const allResources = Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll("script[src], link[rel=stylesheet][href]"),
    ({src, href}) => src || href
  );

console.log(allResources);
```

Alternatively, you could use a `for` loop to iterate over the results.

You can also remove `[rel=stylesheet]` if you’re also interested in fav-icons and other resources.